# selenium web driver Mouse over not working as expected in IE 8

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

In http://www.spicejet.com/ Im trying to click on the link "February 2016" from "About Us">"Spice Route Magazine" and below is the script that I use. There are two questiones:
1) The script works fine in firefox but not in IE. Why? (In IE, the menu keeps flickering and it doesn't time our as well even after 30 sec of implicit wait that I had set) 
2) Even in firefox, the script works only with Thread.sleep and not with conditional wait. Why?

Code:
To mouse over on "About Us"

```
Actions mAction = new Actions(wDriver);
mAction.moveToElement(wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smoothmenu1']/ul/li[2]/a"))).build().perform();
```

To mouse over on "Spice Route Magazine"

```
mAction.moveToElement(wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smoothmenu1']/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/a"))).build().perform();
```

To mouse over and click on "February 2016"

```
mAction.moveToElement(wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smoothmenu1']/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a"))).click().build().perform();
```

With `Thread.sleep(5000)` in between each mouse over, the above code works fine in firefox. But with conditional wait like `owait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smoothmenu1']/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/a"))));` to wait for the visibility of "Spice Route Magazine" and `owait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smoothmenu1']/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a"))));` to wait for the visibility of "February 2016", its not working.

I had tried different locators with link text as well, but of no use. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for a while, done the below settings to the IE driver before initialization and I got it to work:

```
DesiredCapabilities capab = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capab.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING,false);
capab.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS,false);
wDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capab);
```

Still I don't have the answer for my 2nd question..